# Label not sticking to panel C# Visual Studio .NET

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

So I am currently working on a project that are using different panels and I want to place some text on one of them but it seems to get places as a first layer when I want it on the 2rd layer, I will try to show you with GIFs

If you look at the label Auto-Scan it goes on top of all the other panels, And if I send it back it goes to the first panel I want it to get stuck on the "Most" Active panel which is the 2nd one.

[Here is the GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSOTT.gif)

Comment: Was thinking that if I programaticlly add a label but wouldnt it be smarter to go another way? I can do both I just want to know why this first method isnt working

Comment: Also, its only the the "Auto-Size" label that is messing up the other 2 are just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Move the other panel on top of the "Auto-Scan" label.

2) Right-click on the label and select "Send to back" from the pop-up menu.

Comment: I tried doing the same without moving the other panel, now I know I need to do that, thanks!